# I don't find find compatible version of ngx-Permissions with angular 13.3.0

Tags: angular

I am working on angular project.The version I am using of Angular is 13.3.0. I need to install ngx-Permissions. But it's latest version is not compatible with Angular 13.3.0. Which version of ngx-Permissions is compatible with Angular 13.3.0...???

Trying to find ngx-Permissions compatible with Angular 13.3.0